# How are trellis axis limits calculated?

Tags: r, lattice, trellis

Say I want to create an ordinary `xyplot` without explicitly specifying axis limits, then how are axis limits calculated?

The following line of code produces a simple scatter plot. However, axis limits do not exactly range from 1 to 10, but are slightly expanded to the left and right and top and bottom sides (roughly by 0.5).

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(1:10 ~ 1:10, cex = 1.5, pch = 20, col = "black", 
       xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
```

[image: xyplot_axis_extension]

Is there any way to determine the factor by which the axes were expanded on each site, e.g. using `trellis.par.get`? I already tried the following after executing the above-mentioned `xyplot` command:

```
library(grid)
downViewport(trellis.vpname(name = "figure"))
current.panel.limits()
$xlim
[1] 0 1

$ylim
[1] 0 1
```

Unfortunately, the panel limits are returned as normalized parent coordinates, which makes it impossible to obtain the "real" limits. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

**Update:**
Using base-R `plot`, the data range (and consequently the axis limits) is by default extended by 4% on each side, see `?par`. But this factor doesn't seem to apply to 'trellis' objects. So what I am looking for is an analogue to the 'xaxs' (and 'yaxs') argument implemented in `par`.

Comment: Do you want to know how to change it to something else (a different %), or the internal working of lattice on what's the actual arithmetic it uses by default?

Comment: The latter. By the way, I found out that 'trellis' axis limits do agree with the above-mentioned 4% (at least for the code I am using). But where is this expansion factor defined?

Comment: I tried looking into lattice's source code, but no luck. I'm pretty sure it's there somewhere, just didn't have enough time to actually find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Axis limits for `xyplot` are calculated in the `extend.limits` function. This function isn't exported from the lattice package, so to see it, type `lattice:::extend.limits`. Concerning a numeric vector, this function is passed the range of values from the corresponding data (`c(1, 10)` in this example). The final limits are calculated according to the following equation:

```
lim + prop * d * c(-1, 1)
```

- `lim` are the limits of the data, in this case `c(1, 10)`
- `prop` is `lattice.getOption("axis.padding")$numeric`, which by default is `0.07`
- `d` is `diff(as.numeric(lim))`, in this case `9`

The result in this case is `c(0.37, 10.63)`

In case you're interested, the call stack from `xyplot` to `extend.limits` is

1. `xyplot`
2. `xyplot.formula`
3. `limits.and.aspect`
4. `limitsFromLimitList`
5. `extend.limits`

Comment: Marvellous, this is exactly what I've been looking for!